# Read cyrillic from MySql (ASP.NET)

Tags: php, asp.net, mysql

I have a MySql DB with a table

```
CREATE TABLE `pp` (
[...]
`Title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
[...]
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251
```

The table has been populated by PHP and there is a working PHP script that reads the data and write it to a web page.  PHP uses the "windows-1251" encoding and works fine.

Variables on the server sides are:

```
character_set_client:latin1
character_set_connection:latin1
character_set_database:utf8
character_set_filesystem:binary
character_set_results:latin1
character_set_server:latin1
character_set_system:utf8
```

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC3 application that (among other things) reads that data and shows them in a windows-1251 encoded view.
I use MySql .NET Connector v.6.5.4 to connect to DB and read data.

The problem is: cyrillic data on the resulting web-page (i.e. view) are corrupted.

I tried various connection strings with

```
charset=cp1251   or
charset=latin1   or
charset=utf8
```

Further, I trid executing

```
SET NAMES cp1251   or 
SET NAMES latin1   or 
SET NAMES utf8
```

right after the connection, but without any success.

Again: in PHP everything works fine; in ASP.NET does not.

I know that cyrillic text should not be stored in a latin1 column and that PHP works fine because both cp1251 and latin1 are 8-bit-per-character encoding and there is no data conversion.  But I can not replicate that using ASP.NET.

Please help.

Comment: Why do you set this: `Title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
? May be U need set CHARACTER SET cp1251

Comment: The DB is already in production so I can not change it.  My ASP.NET code is supposed only to read from that DB.  There is a lot of other working PHP code which insert/delete/modify DB data.

Answer (score 0):

1 Change field charset to 'cp1251' or 'utf8', e.g. -

```
ALTER TABLE `pp`
  CHANGE COLUMN `Title` `Title` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET cp1251 COLLATE cp1251_general_ci DEFAULT NULL;
```

2 Before inserting or selecting set the connection charset -

```
SET NAMES cp1251;
```

or

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

Comment: 3. Make sure you actually send cp1251 or utf8 encoded data to the database!

Comment: I am unable to change the DB since that would require change of existing PHP code that deal with DB data.  My (ASP.NEt MVC3) applocation is supposed to be read-only.
Note that there are existing PHP pages which displays the data and cyrillic appears just fine.

Comment: Possible that data is stored in cp1251 or utf8 fields, or in binary format, and displayed correctly. But how are you going to store cyrillic in VARCHAR 'latin1' field? You should modify table.

Comment: There is an existing collection of PHP files that deals with that DB - and reading/writing/displaying cyrillic is working fine.
My understanding is that it works fine because both cp1251 and Latin1 are 8-bit and MySql does not perform any conversion. So, whatever PHP writes to - it reads it back and flush unchanged to web page.  That way cyrillic goes unchanged.
I would like to do the same with ASP.NET but, even though I set "charset=latin1" inside connection string and execute "SET NAMES Latin1" before any data reading: once I read text it got somehow changed and it is not cyrillic any more.